# Asymptote: Shipout to SVG not working on MacOS

Tags: diagrams, compiling, asymptote, ghostscript

Running on 2023 M2 Pro Macbook pro, running MacOS Ventura 13.2.1

Hello, I'm unable to export any of my asymptote diagrams as an svg file, although I was able to easily on my old windows machine. This issue has been repeated on 3 different macs, with the same problems appearing every time. The following log illustrates the process I went through to produce these errors on a brand new machine with a fresh install of MacOS Ventura 13.2.1:

1. Installed MacTeX.pkg from tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html and installed it on my machine. In install options, I selected customize and selected all options (ghostscript 10.00, ghostscript dynamic library, GUI applications, TEXLive 2023). Note that `which asy` returns `/Library/TeX/texbin/tex`
2. Then, in `Desktop/Asy-test/` I made a file called `test.asy`, and opened it in VSCode (also downloaded the Asymptote extension on VSCode). The initial contents of `test.asy` were:

```
Settings.outformat = “svg”;
unitsize(fontsize());
Pair a = (0,0);
Pair b = (1,3);
Pair c = (2,4);
Pair d = (-1,1);
draw(a–b–c–d–cycle);
```

The output of `asy test.asy` (after `cd`ing into the correct directory) was:

```
Processing of PostScript specials is disabled (Ghostscript not found)
WARNING: 1 PostScript special ignored. The resulting SVG might look wrong.
```

The svg file was created and was correct. However, in previous attempts of recreating this problem, the svg output did in fact have issues when labels were included (especially if they were rotated).

3. Now, I changed the contents of `test.asy` to:

```
settings.outformat = “svg”;
unitsize(fontsize());
draw(unitcircle());
```

The output of `asy test.asy` was:

```
Processing of PostScript specials is disabled (Ghostscript not found)
XML error: error in path data: number expected (premature end of data)
  _shipout(prefix,f,currentpatterns,format,wait,view,t);
              ^
/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/asymptote/plain_shipout.asy: 116.11: runtime:
    Shipout failed
```

No svg output was created.

4. I ran the first version of `test.asy` (with a,b,c,d) again, and it now also had the XML error + ghostscript error and did not create any output.
5. Now, attempting to fix the ghostscript error, I ran `dvisvgm -V1`, noting that there was no ghostscript in the output. `which gs` returns `/usr/local/bin/gs` and I decided to homebrew install ghostscript. I ran `brew install gs` and now `which gs` returns `/opt/homebrew/bin/gs`.
6. I ran `export LIBGS=/opt/homebrew/lib/libgs.dylib` and now running `dvisvgm -V1` shows ghostscript 10.1.2 Also, running `asy test.asy` now still has the XML error, but no ghostscript error.
7. Attempting to fix the XML error, I `brew install asymptote`, and now `which asy` returns `/opt/homebrew/bin/asy`, and running `/opt/homebrew/bin/asy test.asy` returns:

```
XML error: error in path data: number expected (premature end of data)
    _shipout(prefix,f,currentpatterns,format,wait,view,t);
           ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/asymptote/2.86/share/asymptote/plain_shipout.asy: 116.11: runtime: shipout failed
```

All in all, I have no idea how to fix this XML issue, and why it only started after the second time ever running `asy test.asy`. I am quite certain that the contents of `test.asy` were not an issue, but perhaps something changed behind the scenes after the first time running `asy`? I'm really not sure, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/76903195/2777074

Comment: The issue is probably related to [this dvisvgm bug](https://github.com/mgieseki/dvisvgm/issues/240) which was fixed in version 3.1. So, if possible, update dvisvgm to the latest release and try to create an SVG file with Asymptote again.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the info! I've downloaded the source files from the dvisvgm site, but how do I update/install the new 3.1 version?

Comment: I guess you have to compile the sources yourself or find someone who provides pre-built binaries for your system. As I don't own a Mac, I can't do that. Maybe you could ask the MacTeX team if they offer a more recent version.